# Drop Duplicate row and keep row with the same value in another specified column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I simply want to learn how to remove duplicates, but have more control than 'First' or 'Last' duplicate.
For my specific scenario, I want to examine 2 columns, and when a duplicate is seen in the first column, keep the row which has the same value in the 2nd column as the first one.
Example problem Below

### A : B

543 : 543

123 : 543

221 : 221

123 : 541

123 : 123

Desired output being:

### A : B

543 : 543

221 : 221

123 : 123

Comment: Couldn't you just filter for rows where `A == B` or is there a chance of a unique value in A which doesn't equal B?

Answer (score 3):

Define a third column which states wheather it's the same value, than sort with him, drop the duplicates, and drop the third column:

```
df = df.assign(C=df['A'] != df['B']).sort_values(['A', 'C']).drop_duplicates('A', keep='first').drop('C', axis=1)
```

Comment: I think you can also find simply where ```df['A'] == df['B']```

Comment: @fthomson 1) If there values in column A that don't appear in column B, they would disappear, 2) If there are number of rows that have the same values in A and B, all of them would be kept.

Comment: 1) if im understanding the question you should only keep the row if ```df['A'] == df['B']``` so if a value appears in A and not in B then my assumption would be that you dont keep it. 2) The idea for this would be to drop duplicates after applying mask

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken you want rows where `df['A'] == df['B']` so you could in theory just go

```
df[df['A'] == df['B']].drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```